# How to mock response from AFNetworking with OCMock in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, network-programming, ocmock

This is how I get the instance of my network client:

```
let networkClient = DBNetworkClient(baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://mysite.pl/api"))
```

I also have one method:

```
func citiesWithParameters(parameters: [String: String], completionBlock: DBSearchOptionHandler) {
    
    GET("cities", parameters: parameters, success: { operation, response in
        
        if let error = NSError(response: response) {
            completionBlock([], error)
        } else {
            let cities = DBCity.parseCitiesWithDictionary(response as! NSDictionary)
            completionBlock(cities, nil)
        }
        
        }) { operation, error in
            
            completionBlock([], error)
    }
}
```

This is how I call this method:

```
networkClient.citiesWithParameters(parameters, completionBlock: { cities, error in 
    //do sth 
})
```

This way I pass some parameters, and get the *real* response from server. I would like to mock THAT response when I ask for this. How to do this?

```
func testCities() {

    let mockNetworkClient = OCMockObject.mockForClass(DBNetworkClient.classForCoder())        


    //what should I perform here to be able to do sth like this:

    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("")

    mockNetworkClient.citiesWithParameters(["a": "b"]) { cities, error in
        expectation.fulfill()
        XCTAssertNotNil(cities)
        XCTAssertNil(error) //since I know what is the response, because I mocked this
    }

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(10, handler: nil)
}
```

And this is how my method `GET` is defined within `DBNetworkClient`:

```
override func GET(URLString: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, success: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void)!, failure: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {
    
    return super.GET(URLString, parameters: parameters, success: { (operation, response) in
        
        print("GET \(operation.request.URL)")
        print("GET \(response)")
        
        success(operation, response)
        
        }, failure: { (operation, error) in
            
            print("GET \(operation.request.URL)")
            print("GET \(operation.responseObject)")
            
            failure(operation, error)
    })
}
```

This article: [Writing mock tests for AFNetworking](https://matthiaswessendorf.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/ocmock-and-afnetworking/) is unfortunately not helpful. It is not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have experience with Alamofire therefore I don't know where is declared your `GET` method but you should definitely stub this method instead of `citiesWithParameters`.

For example if it's declared in your `DBNetworkClient`:

```
func testCities()
{
    //1
    class DBNetworkClientMocked: DBNetworkClient
    {
        //2
        override func GET(URLString: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, success: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void)!, failure: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {

            //3
            success(nil, ["San Francisco", "London", "Sofia"])

        }
    }

    //4
    let sut = DBNetworkClientMocked()
    sut.citiesWithParameters(["a":"b"]) { cities, error in

        //5
        XCTAssertNotNil(cities)
        XCTAssertNil(error)

    }
}
```

So what happens here:

1. You define class that is children to `DBNetworkClient`, therefore making a 'Mock' for it as described in article you posted. In that class we will override only methods that we want to change(stub) and leave others unchanged. This was previously done with OCMock and was called Partial Mock.
2. Now you stub it's GET method in order to return specific data, not actual data from the server
3. Here you can define what to return your stubbed server. It can be success failure etc.
4. Now after we are ready with mocks and stubs, we create so called **S**ubject **U**nder **T**est(sut). Please note that if `DBNetworkClient` has specific constructor you must call this constructor instead of default one - ().
5. We execute method that we want to test. Inside it's callback we put all our assertions.

So far so good. However if `GET` method is part of Alamofire you need to use a technique called Dependency Injection(you could google it for more info).

So if `GET` is declared inside another class and is only referenced in citiesWithParameters, how we can stub it? Let's look at this:

```
//1
class DBNetworkClient
{
    //2
    func citiesWithParameters(parameters: [String: String], networkWorker: Alamofire = Alamofire(), completionBlock: DBSearchOptionHandler) {

        //3
        networkWorker.GET("cities", parameters: parameters, success: { operation, response in

            if let error = NSError(response: response) {
                completionBlock([], error)
            } else {
                let cities = DBCity.parseCitiesWithDictionary(response as! NSDictionary)
                completionBlock(cities, nil)
            }

            }) { operation, error in

                completionBlock([], error)
        }

    }
}

func testCities()
{
    //4
    class AlamofireMock: Alamofire
    {
        override func GET(URLString: String!, parameters: AnyObject!, success: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation!, AnyObject!) -> Void)!, failure: ((AFHTTPRequestOperation!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation! {

            success(nil, ["San Francisco", "London", "Sofia"])

        }
    }

    //5
    let sut = DBNetworkClient()
    sut.citiesWithParameters(["a":"b"], networkWorker: AlamofireMock()) { cities, error in

        //6
        XCTAssertNotNil(cities)
        XCTAssertNil(error)

    }
}
```

1. First we have to slightly change our `citiesWithParameters` to receive one more parameter. This parameter is our dependency injection. It is the object that have `GET` method. In real life example it will be better this to be only protocol as `citiesWithParameters` doesn't have to know anything more than this object is capable of making requests.
2. I've set networkWorker parameter a default value, otherwise you need to change all your call to `citiesWithParameters` to fulfill new parameters requirement.
3. We leave all the implementation the same, just now we call our injected object `GET` method
4. Now back in tests, we will mock Alamofire this time. We made exactly the same thing as in previous example, just this time mocked class is Alamofire instead of DBNetworkClient
5. When we call `citiesWithParameters` we pass our mocked object as networkWorker. This way our stubbed `GET` method will be called and we will get our expected data from 'fake' server.
6. Our assertions are kept the same

Please note that those two examples do not use OCMock, instead they rely entirely on Swift power! OCMock is a wonderful tool that we used in great dynamic language - Objective-C. However on Swift dynamism and reflection are almost entirely missing. Thats why even on official [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/swift/) page we had following statement:

> Will there be a mock framework for Swift written in Swift? Maybe. As
>   of now it doesn't look too likely, though, because mock frameworks
>   depend heavily on access to the language runtime, and Swift does not
>   seem to provide any.

The thing that is missing with in both implementations provided is verifying `GET` method is called. I'll leave it like this because that was not original question about, and you can easily implement it with a boolean value declared in mocked class.

One more important thing is that I assume `GET` method in Alamofire is instance method, not a class method. If that's not true you can declare new method inside `DBNetworkClient` which simply calls `Alamofire.GET` and use that method inside `citiesWithParameters`. Then you can stub this method as in first example and everything will be fine.

Comment: `DBNetworkClient` has methods: `GET` and `citiesWithParameters`.

Comment: Why you downvote my answer. If `GET` is declared in `citiesWithParameters` what's not working with my first solution? Only downvote without explanation why you do not like the answer is not constructive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not useful for me, because firstly: what is `Alamofire`?, secondly, this is not mocked there where it should be mocked. i would really like to call my `overriden` `GET` method, to coverage my methods with tests. Is there a way to mock `GET` from the parent of my `DBNetworkClient`? It is expected for me. I would be appreciate if you simplify your answer as much as it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: Ok look only in the first part of the answer. It has nothing to do with Alamofire(which is Swift's equivalent to AFNetworking). Just use the first part until 'so far so good' sentence :)

Comment: No, because this way I do not call my `GET` within `DBNetworkClient`. I would really like to call this anyway, and finally mock the `super.GET` within my `GET` instead of my `GET`. Do you know what I mean? Additionally for each unit test I would need to create subclass of `DBNetworkClient` with its custom `GET` method. Is there a way to avoid this? And mock `super.GET`?

Comment: Ok maybe I misunderstood your question. Usually unit tests are made to test specific method for specific situation(based on input parameters, or state). To consider test reliable it should isolate any external impact. Talking about that do you wan't to test `citiesWithParameters` or `GET` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85276/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-hris-to).